# NAnt using nunit2report with multiple include files

Tags: nunit, nant

I am using nant to generate a report of test results using nunit2report.

I have several projects which I test individually and drop the resulting xml into a common folder.

I then use nant to generate a report using all xml files in this folder.

This works fine at first glance, all the tests seem to be merged into a single html output, however for each file the entire test list is being repeated.

The summaries are related to the summary in a single file but the list of test names are the same and being repeated over and over again.

What I would like ideally is a report where the summaries are merged and only a single list of all test names are displayed.

Is this possible? If not how can I fix the issue of test names being repeated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you restructure your process to run nunit once on all projects (either by specifying multiple assemblies or creating a [nunit project file](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=multiAssembly&r=2.6.2))? This will then alleviate the need to have to merge the xml files.

Comment: this is what we have done in the end. We now create an nunit project file and run all tests to create a single xml file.